# How can I handle F# events in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, f#, event-handling, interop

I am following the method suggested by Don Syme over [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsyme/2010/01/10/async-and-parallel-design-patterns-in-f-reporting-progress-with-events-plus-twitter-sample/) to raise an event and handle it in the GUI.
I have created my event as follows

```
let progressReport = new Event<int>()
```

and have exposed it as follows

```
[<CLIEvent>]
member this.ReportProgress  = progressReport.Publish
```

In my VB.net code, I can see the event and I can even respond to it. However, I can only respond to it if I ignore the int parameter. My code that works is

```
Private Sub test() Handles calcAgent.ReportProgress
    prog.Value += 1
End Sub
```

If I try to change it to

```
Private Sub test(i As int) Handles calcAgent.ReportProgress
    prog.Value += 1
End Sub
```

it won't compile and gives the reason "Method 'test' cannot handle 'ReportProgress' because they do not have a compatible signature."

Comment: If you hover on `calcAgent.ReportProgress`, what type does it show?

Comment: Event.calculationAgent.ReportProgress As Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpHandler(Of Integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `FSharp.Control.FSharpHandler<'T>` [has the signature](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/17b7f2060894d90481aef7c9625b78faa50eddd2/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L3414) of `sender:obj * args:'T -> unit`, which means that the delegate attached to it must have two parameters - `sender:obj` and `args:'T`.

In your case, `'T` is `int`, so your handler should be:

```
Private Sub test(sender As Object, i As int) Handles calcAgent.ReportProgress
    prog.Value += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I was about to respond with "I tried that, doesn't work" but then I thought I better make sure so I copied your code and then it worked! Don't know what I tried earlier but clearly it wasn't this. Thanks!